# implements interface Comparator<T>

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Why does a class that `implements interface Comparator<T>` have to override only the `compare` method of `Comparator<T>`? Why does this class not need to override **all** of the methods in the interface `Comparator<T>`?

Thanks for your answer and time in advance!

Comment: What other methods are there in `Comparator`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Because that is the only non-static, non-default, non-Object method.

Comment: What about the method "boolean equals(Object obj)"?

Comment: Every class / instance has an `equals` inherited from `Object`.

Comment: @AhmedHossam you automatically inherit that from Object

Comment: Not required. Per the doc: *Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object)* and then it goes on to say why you might want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int compare(T o1, T o2) and boolean equals(Object obj) are non-static, non-default method inside Comparator interface
You need to override only compare No need to override equals because Object class having equals method

Comparator interface equals method signature:
boolean equals(Object obj);
and Object class equals method signature
boolean equals(Object obj)

Comment: Same signature for the equals method in the Object class and in the Comparator interface! Wow!

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Comprator<T>` has only one abstract method that must the first non-abstract class, extending such interface, implement: [Comparator - abstract methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

The default methods at the interface are optional to implement.

Comment: They provide "sensible default" method implementations so you don't always have to.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/

Comment: @AhmedHossam Their primary purpose, if I'm not mistaken, is to allow existing interfaces to have methods added without breaking backwards compatibility. But you can also use them to provide default behavior in new interfaces if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: What does backwards compatibility mean? @Slaw

Comment: @AhmedHossam The ability of code compiled against an older version of a library to run with a newer version of that library without having to recompile the code. For example, code compiled with Java 8 should be able to run on Java 16 without recompiling.